# Spring Security, exibir mensagem quando encerrar sessão

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Estou controlando a sessão da minha aplicação com o Spring Security, tenho duas regras para encerrar a sessão, max-session

```
<session-management>
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
            expired-url="/publico/login.jsp" />
</session-management>
```

E tem o timeout

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Solucionou o problema? E quanto a URL `/publico/login.jsp`, não funciona quando expira? E se cria-se um arquivo .jsp quando expira-se com a mensagem quando encerrar a sessão?

Comment: Não solucionei pelo spring, oq eu fiz foi o seguinte, quando da o time out ele corta minha conexão com o banco de dados e acabei tratando diretamente no java com try cat em minha conexão. Não foi a solução mais correta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer com que essa mensagem apareça dizendo que a *session* encerrou, é utilizando um parâmetro na URL (`expired-url="/publico/login.jsp?sessionExpired=sim"`) e ter na página login uma condicional em EL, para fazer verificação para quando esse parâmetro aparecer em sua URL, mostrar o corpo da mensagem.

Ex:

```
${param.sessionExpired}
```

Utilize "param" para pegar qualquer tipo de parametro, é semelhante ao uso de "requestScope" para pegar qualquer atributo setado em uma Session. `${requestScope.nomeDoAtributo}`